# Javascript String.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain why this code isn't working?
(it has been simplified for this example)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var test = 'broken';
  test = test.replace('broken','working');
  console.log(test); // working 

  var field = $('[for="tournament_name"]').html();
  console.log(field); // Tournament Name:
  console.log(typeof field); // string 
  field = field.relpace(':',''); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
});
```

I don't understand why it is saying `replace()` is `undefined`?

I did read through [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), what am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe take 3 seconds to look over your code before posting to StackOverflow?

Comment: Who upvoted this question??

Comment: How is that a down vote? It was a real question, with specifics and a valid error. It may have been a stupid mistake, but still worth it.

Comment: You can't explain how people vote. That aside, this question should be closed as off-topic, due to a typo.

Comment: SO Shouldn't be a "find and fix my bug" service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's a typo:

```
relpace --> replace
```

Comment: i can't believe I did that.

Comment: Flag the question as off-topic, "caused by a simple typographical error".

Comment: Under the question's tags, do you see a link that says "flag"? If not, you may not have enough rep yet to flag it. If so, then you click it and pick the appropriate reason.